# How do I connect a textfield in interface builder to my code in xcode 3.2?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, applescript, textfield

How do I connect a textField in interface builder to my applescript code in xcode 3.2?

I am using **applescript** in **Xcode 3.2**.

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean create a text field box in applescript? If so, then copy this

```
set answer to text returned of (display dialog "Enter the Secret Code:" with title "TextField" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Enter"} default button 2 with hidden answer)
```

Comment: In applescript, sorry for late response. :p